# Browse button in ExtJS

Tags: forms, button, extjs

I need to have a browse button in a window. I need something like...

```
var myWindow = new Ext.window.Window({
                    id:'my-window',
                    height: 200,
                    width: 400,
                    layout: 'fit',
                    buttons:[browseButton]
                    });
```

So I guess I can't use the filefield in there since I need it to be in the window's button config.

Is there any button or maybe a handler I can use to create a button that pops up a browse window like the ones in filefield do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a config item on the field to only show the button for example, this works:

```
    myButton = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.File', {
        buttonOnly: true,
        hideLabel: true,
        listeners: {
            'change': function(button, value){
                alert('Selected: '+ value);
            }
        }
    });    

    // your window example
    var myWindow = new Ext.window.Window({
        id:'my-window',
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        layout: 'fit',
        buttons:[myButton]
    });

    myWindow.show();
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that even if I was using buttonOnly it would treat it like a field and wouldn't let me add it in the buttons property.